# Alternator health check

Tags: battery, alternator, power-steering, charging, battery-testing

My car (Fiat Grande Punto MY2008) has been having an occassional battery light and failure of the power steering. Perhaps once in every 10-15 startups, and is resolved by restarting the car.

The car starts fine, but I am concerned the alternator isn't putting out enough power. So I have taken some readings, which seem a little on the low side to me but not bad enough to strongly indicate the alternator is faulty.

I've taken battery voltage readings, which are as follows:

- with engine off: **12.4v**
- with engine on (idling)

  - no electricals on: **14.1v**
  - some electricals on (fan at max speed/aircon/lights): **13.8v**
  - whilst turned steering wheel with above electricals on: **fluctuates, but stays above 13v**
  - all electricals on (above + rear windscreen heater): **fluctuates, drops below 13v**

I ceased testing with the rear windscreen heater turned on, as the voltage on the multimeter kept dropping and I was concerned it would drop below 12.4v

Applying some revs to the engine didn't make a noticable difference to the voltage. My understading is that the alternator should output almost 100% power at idle speed anyway. The battery is new.

Comment: Does this car have electrical power steering?

Comment: @GdD Yes it does, and this model is known for EPS failure. Reference: https://www.ecutesting.com/common-faults/fiat/fiat-grande-punto-electric-power-steering-column-eps/

Answer (score 3):

The voltage readings sound fairly normal to me.  Also, since you don't get fluctuating voltages depending on RPM, I would suspect the voltage regulator is also good.

I would check elsewhere. Electrical short maybe, or failing electric steering box, or ECU?